# Mocha async afterEach hook not waiting

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, mocha.js

I am running some tests for CRUD operations using `sequelize` framework.
After each test, I want to delete all the records in a table, but that is not happening.
When I run all the tests, the `create` test fails because the records count is greater than 1:

```
Database shall be empty: expected 1 to equal 0
```

When I run only the `create` test, it works just fine, so I suppose that there is a problem with `forEach` hook.
When I use the `after` hook it works fine, deleting all the records from the table.

```
describe('User CRUD', () => {
    before(async () => {
        await db.user.sync()
    })

    afterEach(async () => {
        // delete all records
        await db.user.destroy({ where: {} })
    })

    // after(async () => {
        // delete all records
    //    await db.user.destroy({ where: {} })
    // })

    it('create', async () => {
        // start with no hosts
        let usersCount = await db.user.count()
        chai.expect(usersCount).to.equal(0, 'Database shall be empty')

        // adding one user
        const newUser1 = await db.user.create(user1)

        usersCount = await db.user.count()

        chai.expect(newUser1.username).to.equal('admin', 'Username does not match')
        chai.expect(newUser1.password).to.equal('adminPw', 'Password does not match')
        chai.expect(usersCount).to.equal(1, 'Database shall have one inserted record')

        // adding second user
        const newUser2 = await db.user.create(user2)

        usersCount = await db.user.count()

        chai.expect(newUser2.username).to.equal('user', 'Username does not match')
        chai.expect(newUser2.password).to.equal('userPw', 'Password does not match')
        chai.expect(usersCount).to.equal(2, 'Database shall have one inserted record')
    })

    it('delete', async () => {
        // adding one host
        const newUser1 = await db.user.create(user1)
        await newUser1.destroy()

        let usersCount = await db.user.count()

        chai.expect(usersCount).to.equal(0, 'Database shall not have inserted records')
    })

    it('errors', async () => {
        const createDuplicatedRole = async () => {
            await db.user.create(user1)
            await db.user.create(user1)
        }

        chai.expect(createDuplicatedRole()).to.be.rejectedWith(db.sequelize.UniqueConstraintError, 'User with same username does already exist.')
    })
})
```

What am I doing wrong?